# Passing PySpark pandas_udf data limit?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyspark, user-defined-functions, databricks

The problem is simple. Please observe the code below.

```py
@pyf.pandas_udf(pyt.StructType(RESULTS_SCHEMA_LIST), pyf.PandasUDFType.GROUPED_MAP)
def train_udf(df):
    return train_ml_model(df=df)

results_df = complete_df.groupby('training-zone').apply(train_udf)
```

One of the columns of the `results_df` is typically a very large string (>4e6 characters). While this isn't a problem for a `pandas.DataFrame` or a `spark.DataFrame` when I convert the pandas dataframe to a spark dataframe. It is a problem when the `pandas_udf()` attempts to do this. The error returned is `pyarrrow.lib.ArrowInvalid could not convert **string** with type pyarrow.lib.StringValue: did not recognize the Python value type when inferring an Arrow data type`

This UDF does work if I don't return the problematic column or I make the problematic column only contain some small string such as 'wow that is cool', so I know the problem is not with the udf itself per se.

I know the function `train_ml_model()` works because when I get a random group from the spark dataframe then convert it to a pandas dataframe and pass it to train_ml_model() it produces the expected pandas dataframe with the column with a massive string.

I know spark can handle such large strings because when I convert the pandas dataframe to a spark dataframe using `spark.createDataFrame()` the spark dataframe contains the full expected value.

PS: Why is pyarrow even trying to infer the datatype when I pass the types to the `pandas_udf()`?

Any help would be very much appreciated!